# specify recipient Youtube api v3 insert comment

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

On youtube when I tap `Reply` button under a non top level comment, the recipient user gets mentioned at the start of the message `@Philip ...`. How can I replicate this behavior with an api v3? My main goal is to notify the reply owner.
I've tried specifying `parentId`, but it looks like only top level comment can be passed into this property.
Also I've tried specifying `@Philip` and `@CHANNEL_ID` at the message start - it doesn't creates a link.

I've inspected commenting in Chrome, and it sends "create_comment_reply" request, which seems like private api

Answer (score 0):

Mentions are only for replies to comments in a top-level comment.

Youtube Data API v3 only supports replies to top-level comment. One cannot currently comment to a comment to top-level comment using the API.

In the docs for [parameters for comments/list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list#parameters), they note that:

> Note: YouTube currently supports replies only for top-level comments. However, replies to replies may be supported in the future.

When comments are supported for comments to top-level comments, it may be possible to perform mentions.